# How to add an if statement to a for loop?

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop

I've got a working php script that I need soem help modifying.

Here is my script:

```
<? $images = $product->images;
for ($i = 4; $i <= 8; $i++): ?>
<li>
<a href='<?= $images[$i]->getThumbnailPath(0,0) ?>' class="swatch_lbox_gallery" rel="gal">
<img src="<?= $images[$i]->getThumbnailPath(138, 0) ?>"/>
</a>   
<p><?= $images[$i]->title ?><br/>
<?= $images[$i]->description ?></p>
</li>
<? endfor; ?>
```

it does work when there are 4+ images, otherwise I get an error. I've tried to add an if statement to this so it hides if there is no 4th image, but I just can't get it to work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I need to add more detail.

Added detail - I'm starting at 4, because I need images 4-8

Thanks!

Steph

Comment: What error are you getting??.And why are you initializing the value of $i=4 in the loop?

Comment: have you tried with `$i = 0; $i <= 8; $i++` why you starting loop with `$i=4 `

Comment: In regards to `Barmar's` answer, if you were to only have 4 images in your folder, then your `$i = 4;` technically won't work. Have you tested to see with only 4 images? Logically, the `4` actually means `5`. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (count($images) >= 4) for ($i = 4; $i <= 8; $i++):
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<? 
    $images = $product->images;
    $startOnImage = 4;
    $endOnImage = 8;

    foreach($images as $key => $image)
    {
        if($key<$startOnImage){ continue; }
        if($key>$endOnImage){ break; }

        echo '<li>';
        echo '<a href="' . $image->getThumbnailPath(0,0) . '" class="swatch_lbox_gallery" rel="gal">';
        echo '<img src="' . $image->getThumbnailPath(138, 0) . '"/>';
        echo '</a>';

        echo '<p>' . $image->title . '<br/>';
        echo $image->description . '</p>';
        echo '</li>';

     }
```

Comment: Better edit :)! +1

Infact - Change `$image[$key]`, should just be `$image->title` or `$images[$key]`

Comment: @Farkie +1, Thanks for pointing that out! An error on my part, should have seen it!

Comment: This will display all images. It looks like he wants to start at #4.

Comment: @Barmar I have edited the code to make it easier to start and end on certain images.

Comment: @Barmar Um... I think the OP is a `she`. Hence, `Stephanie` ;-) Unless she lied to me!

Comment: @Stephanie Glad I put a `:D` on your face, cheers! Now where did put my `escape` key?!

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 4; $i <= min(8, count($images)-1); $i++) :
```

The `-1` is necessary because numeric array indexes start with 0, not 1. So `$images[4]` requires that `count($images)` be at least 5.

Comment: Hi All,Thank you so much for all the help!
Technically both Gamag and Phil Cross's suggestions work, so both are correct.
I'm going to start by using Gamag's, and hold off on selecting the "correct" answer till the client approves.
I hope that works for you, thank you so much!!

Comment: @Stephanie `Barmar` has a point on the numeric array index thingy. Gawd, I had forgotten about. See what `age` does? TIP: Don't get `old`.